# "Refresh Recordset" command gives error "There are pending changes. Please commit or rollback first."

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbench v8.0, in the query part of the window, I entered many new lines of data (using the INSERT command) into my table.

However, the new data did not appear in the visual view of the table in MySQL Workbench.

I hit the "refresh" button on the result grid that shows the contents of the table, but I got the error message under "Action Output" that said the "Refresh Recordset" had failed because "There are pending changes. Please commit or rollback first."

When I have a command-line view of my table concurrently running (at the same time as MySQL Workbench), it shows that my database has indeed made the data updates that were made with the previous INSERT commands using the Workbench GUI.  (So, the log shown under the "Action Output" part of the Workbench GUI appears to be correct, which says that MySQL ran the INSERT commands.)

So, the update to my table has been made using the GUI MySQL Workbench, but I can't refresh the view of the table contents in MySQL Workbench. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that I had also been in the middle of an edit to my table using the MySQL Workbench GUI visual view of the table. It wouldn't allow me to update the visual view of the table until I had selected "Apply" or "Revert" to the edits I was making.

Once I selected "Apply" to the result grid, the table finally refreshed the view of its contents!

Comment: Exactly was my case.

Comment: where is the apply button?